# Ninject keep this same DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject

I'm having issues with DbContext,

```
class RepoA : IRepoA {
   public RepoA(IDbContext context)...
}

class RepoB : IRepoB{
    public RepoB(IDbContext context)...
}
```

and Ninject

```
kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.bind<IDbContext>().to<DbContext>();
kernel.bind<IRepoA>().to<RepoA>();
kernel.bind<IRepoB>().to<RepoB>();
```

And in this case, IDbContext was created twice. 
I want for RepoA and RepoB to share the same IDbContext object

Is there a way of doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Scoping (see https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes). E.g. binding `DbContext` in singleton scope like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IDbContext>().To<DbContext>().InSingletonScope();
```

should let the repositories share object. `InSingletonScope()` may not be the right scope for your purposes, though, it depends on your application.